# Clear Local storage when user killed the Cordova app from background apps in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

I am developing a Cordova application. I would like to clear the Local Storage data stored in the Cordova App when user kills the app from the background apps.

I tried using
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

It giving me a log when user quits the app.

From this method how can i clear the data data stored:

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`